# Run Time '424' Error on ws.delete inside a loop

Tags: vba, excel

I cant seem to figure out why this is throwing an error, and only the first time through. When a user's logs on a sheet for Expense and Income are created for each user the logging in user has access too. It is copied from a Master Expense Page and Master Income Page respectively. On logout, a sub is called to removes these added page and can be found below:

**NOTE:** The ***onclick*** logout procedure call one, than the other.

```
Public Sub removeExpensePages()
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        On Error Resume Next
            If ws.Name Like "*" & "Expense Page" & "*" Then
                If ws.Name <> "Master Expense Page" Then
                    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                    ws.Delete
                    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
                End If
            End If
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next
End Sub
Public Sub removeIncomePages()

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        On Error Resume Next
            If ws.Name Like "*" & "Income Page" & "*" Then
                If ws.Name <> "Master Income Page" Then
                    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                    ws.Delete
                    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
                End If
            End If
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Is the code located in a module or a sheet?

Comment: My guess is that as the worksheet is deleted, the enumeration of the worksheets gets affected, because of which the `For Each` loop cannot function. The first alternative that comes to mind is to store the names of the found worksheets in a string array, and then use their names to delete by iterating through that array. Worth a try I would say.

Comment: MrDogme: The code is located in a module and is called from a UserForm

Comment: shash: I have tried that, and receive the same error when iterating through the array.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seemed to work for me. However, since I've already tested it and made a few improvements, I'll post them up:

- The two subs can be reduced to one
- `Option Explicit` is essential, I immediately noticed that the `wb` and `ws` variables were undeclared
- The `wb` variable wasn't really necessary, just use `ThisWorkbook` instead
- `On Error Resume Next` just hides the issues, it doesn't help you solve them.

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub removeAllPages()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name Like "*Expense Page*" Or ws.Name Like "*Income Page*" Then
            If ws.Name <> "Master Expense Page" And ws.Name <> "Master Income Page" Then
                Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                ws.Delete
                Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            End If
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```

---

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: Both ws and wb are declared above the sub's themselves. Along with option explicit. I pasted the above code and the error is still being thrown. Again, only the first time Logout is selected. If selected again, all of the pages are removed without error. Its weird.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through worksheets by their index backwards from last one to the first

Furthermore, you may use a single sub accepting the “master” sheet name

Finally it’s best logic to swap the two checks

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub RemovePages(masterName As String)
    Dim iWs As Long
    Dim wsName As String

    With ThisWorkbook
        For iWs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count to 1 Step -1
            With .Sheets(iWs)
                If .Name <>  masterName Then
                    If .Name Like "*" & masterName & "*" Then
                         Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                         .Delete
                         Application.DisplayAlerts = True
                    End If
                End If
            End With
       Next
    End With
End Sub
```

So that your onclick sub can call it passing the two “Master” names

```
Sub onclick()
    RemovePages "Expense Page"
    RemovePages "Master Income Page"
End Sub
```

Comment: I was getting the error for each ws being deleted for the above code.

Comment: You must give more details about your “environment” (where is onClick() sub, what calls it, under which conditions...)

Comment: Logout on Click is located on a UserForm and the only way it is called is when a user clicks the Logout commandbutton. Clicking it does the following:
Sets the current user class to nothing
Calls a logout procedure which has the following calls:
emptySessionVariables (Clears a range in another hidden sheet)
removeExpensePage (where the issue is)
removeIncomePage (where the issues is) 
NOTE: The are now combined
AND
hideAllPages (where all remaining pages are hidden with the exception of the first page.)

Answer (score 0):

So, I'm not sure what the fix was, but it had to do with something in the code located on the Master sheets themselves. Perhaps an object was being referenced that was no longer available upon the ws.delete? I have since re-worked all of that code and am no longer receiving the run time error. Thanks to all who helped me on this!!!